# How to check if the web element is in the upper left corner

Tags: java, selenium, junit, assert

I have to check if the logo is displayed in the upper left corner. I downloaded the element's location and I do not know how to write the assertions in JUnit.

```
Point loc = driver.findElement(By.className("hdr_logo")).getLocation();
```

Location is (0,128)

checking if x and y is smaller than 200 is a good idea?

Comment: This sounds like a fragile test requirement that will vary across devices and display resolutions...

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the dimensions of the browser window:

```
int winHeight = driver.manage().window().getSize().getHeight();
int winWidth = driver.manage().window().getSize().getWidth();
```

Then you need to get the position AND size of the web element:

```
WebElement logo = driver.findElement(By.className("hdr_logo"));
int xPos = logo.getLocation().getX();
int yPos = logo.getLocation().getY();
int eleHeight = logo.getSize().getHeight();
int eleWidth = logo.getSize().getWidth();
```

In order to check to see if it's in the upper-left quadrant of the screen, the lower-right most pixel must be within the bounds of half the browser window height and width:

```
Assert.assertTrue((xPos + eleWidth) <= winWidth/2) && (yPos + eleHeight) <= winHeight/2), "Logo is NOT in the upper left quadrant");
```